# Get container children size, on resize Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have some code that gets the heights of the child divs of a container div,

Adds the heights to an array, gets the max number of the array (i.e the tallest div) then loops through the divs and sets the heights to the tallest div (i.e makes them equal height)

When the view loads it works very well, however on window resize the height array only updates when the children divs heights are larger than before, but not smaller

i.e. when the page loads the height of children divs = 600px;

I resize the window to make it smaller the height remains 600px and the spaces between the divs increases

When I resize the window to make it larger the heights updates

```
public setHeight(){

  this.divHeights = []
  let maxHeight:number;

  let divChildren = this.parentDiv.nativeElement.children
    for (let i = 0; i < divChildren.length; i++){
      let divHeights = divChildren[i].clientHeight
      this.divHeights.push(divHeights);
    }
    maxHeight = Math.max( ...this.divHeights )


    for (let i = 0; i < divChildren.length; i++){
    this.renderer.setStyle(divChildren[i], 'min-height', maxHeight+"px")
    }
}
```

I was wondering if anyone has come across this behaviour before

Answer (score 0):

For anyone getting issues with equal height divs;

What I ended up doing was updating bootstrap in the project to 4, this version handles this issue perfectly